# How should memory be freed after an exception is thrown in C++?

Tags: exception, memory, malloc, c++03

I apologize if this question is a duplicate - I searched for a while, but it's possible that my Google-fu just isn't up to snuff.

I am modifying a C++ program that calls into a C library.  The C library allocates a bunch of memory (using `malloc()`), and the C++ program uses it and then frees it.  The catch is that the C++ program can throw an exception midway through execution, causing the allocated memory to never be freed.

As a (rather contrived) example:

```cpp
/* old_library.c */
char *allocate_lots() {
    char *mem = (char *)malloc(1024);
    return mem;
}

/* my_prog.cpp */
void my_class::my_func () {
    char *mem = allocate_lots();
    bool problem = use(mem);
    if (problem)
        throw my_exception("Oh noes! This will be caught higher up");
    free(mem);  // Never gets called if problem is true
}
```

My question is: how ought I to deal with this?  My first idea was to wrap the whole thing in a try/catch block, and in the catch just check and free the memory and re-throw the exception, but this seems graceless and clunky to me (and wouldn't work well if I want to *actually* catch an exception).  Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT:** I probably should have mentioned that we're using g++ 4.2.2, from back in 2007 before std::unique_ptr was introduced.  Chalk it up to corporate inertia.

Comment: Why can't you just free the memory before throwing the exception?

Comment: Use RAII, problem solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter that calls free:

```
class free_mem {
public:
    void operator()(char *mem) { free(mem); }
};

void my_class::my_func() {
    std::unique_ptr<char, free_mem> mem = allocate_lots();
```

Comment: This would probably be the right answer, except that we're using an old version of g++ (see the edit above).

Comment: Write your own unique_ptr replacement, then explain to your boss why you spent 2 days debugging a basic language tool that you would have gotten for free if they allowed upgrading. Repeat it until they start weighting the time wasted with outdated tools against the time spent upgrading.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap that rascal:

```
struct malloc_deleter {
  template <typename T>
  void operator () (T* p) const {
    free(p);
  }
};

void my_class::my_func () {
    std::unique_ptr<char[],malloc_deleter> mem{allocate_lots()};
    bool problem = use(mem.get());
    if (problem)
        throw my_exception("Oh noes! This will be caught higher up");
}
```

Comment: Mmm. Can you explain the use of `char[]`?

Comment: `unique_ptr<T[]>` is a partial specialization that overloads `operator []` instead of `operator ->` and uses `delete[]` by default (obvously not important here).

Comment: I'm eternally confused with that, then. I thought `shared_ptr` had that. But apparently, they forgot to add the same for `shared_ptr`

Comment: Correct. `boost::shared_ptr` has a `T[]` specialization, but it was added after the standard swallowed `shared_ptr` in TR1. (See [this thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/shared-array-Why-not-in-C-11-td4649418.html)).

Comment: This would probably be the right answer, except that we're using an old version of g++ (see the edit above).

Answer (score 4):

You should make sure that you don't throw until after you have freed the memory - or that you use a suitable smart pointer structure to store the `mem`, such that when the `throw` happens, and the stack unwinds, the `mem` gets freed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using an old compiler version that doesn't have `unique_ptr`, you can write your RAII wrapper yourself:

```
class ResourceWrapper {
public:
    ResourceWrapper(char* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
    ~ResourceWrapper() { free(m_ptr); }
    // whatever getters suit you, at the very least:
    char* get() const { return m_ptr; }
private:
    char* const m_ptr;
};

void my_class::my_func () {
    ResourceWrapper mem(allocate_lots());
    bool problem = use(mem.get());
    if (problem)
        throw my_exception("Oh noes! This will be caught higher up");
}
```

Just make sure **not** to allow copy/assignment even implicitly (which is why I made `m_ptr` const) or you'd risk ending up with double-freeing your memory ("move" semantics à la `auto_ptr` are best avoided unless you *absolutely* need it).

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use `std::unique_ptr`, you could create your own deleter class that would control the lifetime of the pointer in RAII fashion. To keep it simple this example doesn't wrap the actual pointer but exists alongside it; a safer approach would be to make a true smart pointer class.

```
class AutoFree
{
public:
    AutoFree(void* p) : m_p(p)
    {
    }
    ~AutoFree()
    {
        free(m_p);
    }
private:
    void* m_p;
};

void my_class::my_func () {
    char *mem = allocate_lots();
    AutoFree mem_free(mem);
    bool problem = use(mem);
    if (problem)
        throw my_exception("Oh noes! This will be caught higher up");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to simply free the memory inside the if clause?

```
if (problem) {
    free (mem);
    throw my_exception ("Drat!");
}
```

Comment: Duplication of code, although in this specific case the `free` could really be moved before the conditional altogether. Long-term, there's a danger that someone unaware of what's going on here could insert another `throw` or `return` or call to another function that could throw without handling the fragile resource. RAII protects against the next guy being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Use unique_ptr: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cd3f0fc64d99cc07a2350e2ff9686500-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>

/* old_library.c */
char *allocate_lots()
{
    return static_cast<char*>(malloc(1024));
}

struct my_exception : virtual std::exception {
    const char* const msg;
    my_exception(const char* const msg) : msg(msg) {}
    const char* what() const noexcept { return msg; }
};

struct my_class
{
    struct Free { void operator() (char* p) const { free(p); } };
    /* my_prog.cpp */
    void my_func()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<char, Free> mem;

        mem.reset(allocate_lots());
        bool problem = use(mem.get());

        if(problem)
        {
            throw my_exception("Oh noes! This will be caught higher up");
        }
    }

    static bool use(char*) { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    my_class prog;
    prog.my_func();
}
```

Comment: @Dan replace `unique_ptr` by [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) if you don't have it